# Hibernate ignore field in select statement, but cache it

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I have some `@Entity@Table(***)@Cache(*****.TRANSACTIONAL)` POJO class with getters and setters of table fields, one of then if `@Column(***)getPostText()`. I want to add a new one getter method

```
public void getPostTextParsed() {
   return this.postText.replace("a", "+++");
}
```

but I got `Unknown column myTable.postTextParsed in 'field list'`.

I tried to annotate it with `@Transient`, Exception solved, but after that this field is not cached. Ie, when I call this method `getPostTextParsed()`, it executes each time, without caching.

How to exclude `getPostTextParsed()` from selection, to prevent exception `Unknown column myTable.postTextParsed...`, but, in same time, to cache results of this method after first execution of it?

I use Hibernate 5.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you use a @Formula?

Comment: No, I need to code a very complex regular expression replacement with 3 tables cross links. It could be coded only by Java, not by SQL.